# WP7 Update Tile locally

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, tiles

is there a possibility in WP7 to update a tile from the depending application. For example a weather service that updates the tile every hour (ShellTileSchedule).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the current (7.0 / pre-mango tools) the way to update the tile locally is via the ShellTileSchedule. Alternatively you could try sending the TileNotification push notification from your app. (Note that I haven't tried this myself and I've heard mixed reports of how successful this is.) You can't do this when the app isn't running though.

Comment: Yes, I know. But is it possible to execute some code on update which modifies the tile (i.e. check for new weather conditions)?

Comment: in which case what is your question?

Comment: Ok, a sample: I have a weather app which displays the current condition on the tile. So after one hour I want to update the current condition and refresh the tile. Ok?

Comment: With ShellTileSchedule code isn't executed on the recurrence interval it just requests the URI again. If you want the image to be updated you need to dynamically generate or return a different image on the server side. A good example of creating a schedule is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/11/24/live-tiles-on-a-schedule.aspx Be sure to see comments for additional information

Comment: Well that's the point. So a local update won't work. Thanks for info!